# Target elements by class prefix

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have the elements as below:

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="tab231891230"></div>
  <div class="tab121232441"></div>
  <div class="tab123134545"></div>
</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to select the div elements that have the class starting with `"tab"`?

Comment: Just a general comment about classes vs. ids: classes should broadly match a "class" of multiple items and ids should match specific items. In general "tab1234567" is something specific, which means you should use an "id" and not a class. But sometimes you don't have a choice if the code is already written :-)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It is called the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). My example sets a red text color on the elements:

```
$('[class^="tab"]').css('color', 'red');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ypkwJ/203/)

Please note that if the elements have more than one class and the other precedes the one with `tab` inside (`class="nyedva tab231891230"`) the element won't be selected by this selector.

If you want to select even these, you can use this example:

```
$('.home div').filter(function () {
    return this.className.match(/\btab/);
}).css('color', 'red');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ypkwJ/2/)

Comment: @SyedQarib Why would not it work? Just replace `.home div` with simply `div`.

Comment: Sorry about that, was trying to filter more tags then just divs but now have the idea how to do it .. thanks

Comment: @lowtechsun What do you want to tell us with this jsFiddle link?

Comment: @kapa just added $ to your fiddle so people can see what it does in action.

Comment: @lowtechsun I see now, thanks. Will edit into my answer.

Answer (score 46):

If you have multiple class inside one element, use this to select

```
$("[class*='tab']");
```

It will work with element like this

```
<div class="home">
<div class="module tab231891230"></div>
<div class="module tab121232441"></div>
<div class="module tab123134545"></div>
```

Reference : [jquery attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: Be aware that this will also select classes like `timetable`, resulting in "strange" bugs.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it like this:

```
$('div[class^="tab"]');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: I'm afraid that actually won't work because there's a typo (I've just blindly copied it and got 'unrecognized expression' error message). There's one too many equals sign, and the correct syntax is: $('div[class^="tab"]');

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: try always to use a **[Safe Delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20811902/383904)** like `-` I.e: `tab-something`

The **proper way** to select class by prefix is by using a **combination** of two [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), the `^` ***Starts With*** and `*` ***Includes***.

The reason being: by using only: `[class^="tab-something"]` such will select only `class="tab-something foo bar"` but **not** `class="foo tab-something bar"` elements — giving you **erratic results.**

## Target elements by className prefix

**JavaScript:**

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="tab-"], [class*=" tab-"]');
```

**jQuery:**

```js
const $tabs = $('[class^="tab-"], [class*=" tab-"]');
```

**CSS:**

```css
[class^="tab-"], [class*=" tab-"] {
  /* "tab-" prefixed class styles here */
}
```

To recap:
the above will make sure to target both `"tab-aaa foo bar"` and `"foo tab-bbb bar"`

Answer (score -3):

why use that? that number, you can assign to rel or id attribute, like this:

```
<div class="home">
    <div class="tab" rel="231891230"></div>
    <div class="tab" rel="121232441"></div>
    <div class="tab" rel="123134545"></div>
</div>
```

then it will be accessible at:

```
$('div.tab').click(yourhandler);
```

or even, add a subclass of that current "tab" class:

```
<div class="home">
    <div class="tab 231891230"></div>
    <div class="tab 121232441"></div>
    <div class="tab 123134545"></div>
</div>
```

then, just select by "tab" class like in the jQuery example above,
and do whatever you want with the second class (check if it's there,
remove it).

check these:

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: The right way to store values in your approach is a `data-` attribute.

Comment: also, classes cannot begin with numbers

Comment: Rather than criticizing the example, perhaps try to answer the question:  Yes, the class names in the OP's question are poor examples, but the question is still valid.