# How can I remove all classes starting with a prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery removeClass wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644299/jquery-removeclass-wildcard)
>   [jQuery - Select an element that the class starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055355/jquery-select-an-element-that-the-class-starts-with)

I have some divs that that belong to zone (a div may have class "zoneA", another div may have class "zoneB", etc.). I want to be able to select multiple divs of that kind, and set a new class to them.

So I would like to do something like:

`$(".selected-divs").removeClass("zone*").addClass(".zone-new")`

How can I remove all classes in this maner?

Comment: This question looks like it will solve it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220851/element-or-class-like-selector-for-jquery

Comment: Similar question asked and solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812/remove-all-classes-that-begin-with-a-certain-string