# Why hyphen (-) separated class names are widely used in CSS

Tags: html, css

While gone through some of the CSS files included with some websites and some other widely used plugins and frameworks, found that they are widely using hyphen separated words as class names. Actually what is the advantage of using such class names.

**For example: 
In jquery UI CSS,**

```
.ui-helper-reset {

    // CSS properties here...

}
```

Comment: It's more readable than `.uihelperreset`.

Comment: @BoltClock is it that the only thing behind this, or will it enhance any easier selection methods?

Comment: Readability but also: In some text editors by double-clicking the name it'll select just a text-portion like: ui-`helper`-reset while using underscore it'll select the whole name: `ui_helper_reset`. Makes it more easier to change or select all and modify in the whole doc just the needed specific name property.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Is that editor Sublime Text? :P

Comment: @PraveenKumar Notepad++, Sublime2 and Netbeans, even jsFiddle and jsBin AFAIK

Comment: @BoltClock what about these kind of selections `col[class*="col-"]`, Does this hyphen plays any role here?

Comment: That does play a role. For example it ensures you don't accidentally select classes like `column`.

Comment: Hyphens allow for css2 Pipe patterns, in my opinion useful for version selection. Example: `<span class="ver-1-1-2 wrapper">Ver 1.1.2</span>
<span class="special ver-1-2-3 slick">Ver 1.2.3</span>` and css rules `span[class*=ver-1-2]{ font-weight:bold; }
span[class*=ver-1]{ color:red; }` will match desired sub-sets of versions.
https://codepen.io/jensf/pen/Gyvzdv

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### Readability:

`ui-helper-reset` readable,
`uiHelperReset` unreadable.

### Safe delimiter:

When using *[attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)* like `[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"]` to specifically and safely target the specific classname styles by prefix, while preventing i.e: `.iconography` to be matched.

### Ease of use:

In every **decent code editor**, if you use `-` to separate *combined-class-name* you can **easily highlight** a desired portion by **double-click**ing it like: **col-`md`-3**, and replace it (or even document globally) to **col-`sm`-3**. On the other hand, if you use *underscore* `_` like **class_name_here**, if you double-click it you'll end up highlighting the whole class-name like: **`class_name_here`**. Such will force you to manually drag-select the desired portion instead.

### CSS Naming Convention Methodology

You can adopt a CSS naming concept like:

- **SUIT CSS**
- **BEM** (Block, Element, Modifier),
- **OOCSS** (Object-Oriented CSS)
- **SMACSS** (Scalable and Modular Architecture for CSS)
- **Atomic CSS**
- …**Your Own Concept** CSS :)

They all help a team speak *"the same language"*, by adopting a stricter *"Naming things"* such as:

### [SUIT CSS](https://suitcss.github.io/)

```css
/* Block */
.Chat{}

/* -element (child) */
.Chat-message{} 

/* --modifier */
.Chat-message--me{}   /* Style my messages differently from other messages */

/* .is-state */
.Chat.is-active{}     /* Multiple chats - active state handled by JS */
```

or

### [BEM](http://getbem.com/):

```css
/* block */
.chat{}

/* __element (child) */
.chat__message{} 

/* --modifier */
.chat__message--me{}   /* Style my messages differently from other messages */
.chat--js-active{}     /* Multiple chats - active state handled by JS */
```

If your `.chat` is part of the page you're viewing, you could use general Block classes like `.btn` and Modifier `.btn--big` like `<a class="btn btn--big">Post</a>`, otherwise if your buttons need a stricter styling specific to your chat application than you'd use `.chat__btn` and `.chat__btn--big` classes. Such classnames can also be preprocessed.

### SCSS

I.e: by using [**Sass** SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/), a *superset* of CSS3 sintax you can do stuff like:

<sub>(Example using SUIT CSS)</sub>

```css
.Chat {
  font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 300px;
  height: 360px;

  &-message {                 // refers to .Chat-message
    padding: 16px;
    background: #eee;

    &--me {                   // refers to .Chat-message--me
      background: #eef;       // Style my messages differently from other messages */
      text-align: right;
    }
  }

  &.is-active {               // refers to .Chat.is-active (JS)
    outline: 3px solid lightblue;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```css
<div class="Chat is-active">
  <div class="Chat-message">Hi </div>
  <div class="Chat-message Chat-message--me">Ciao!<br>How are you? </div>
  <div class="Chat-message">Fine thx! Up for a ☕?</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wfsL1opc/)

---

#### Conclusion:

Adopting a stricter **naming format** among a team **is important**. Prevents and minimizes dead legacy classes bloating your HTML, helps code re-usability, readability and speeds up your workflow. Additionally, it *forces* you and your team to think in a much more modular way about your HTML structure - as **components** or **atoms**.
Whatever you decide to use is up to you - **just, be consistent**.

Comment: @PrasanthKC exactly, building huge *stylesheets* even I use combined class-names. The hyphen here is just our friend. Less time spent on the machine `-` more making coffee. :D

Comment: Why not use camelCase ?  `uiHelperReset` is more readable than either of other options.

Comment: @CharlesBretana camelCase is readable as any other way that suits you best. The difference between `camelCase` and `camel-not-case` is that I can quickly edit my `not` into `bloody` by just double-clicking at it in most editors, while in your case I would use the click+shift+keyboardArrows or had to precisely drag-select the word portion I want to change. Hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 5):

It is just a practice for **readability**. Generally, you cannot have such variables in JavaScript, for separator, as `-` is an operator. When you need separator in JavaScript, you either use something of these:

```
.ui_helper_reset //snake_case
.uiHelperReset //camelCase
```

This way you can differentiate that one is used for CSS and other is for JavaScript. This is my point of view, but can be applied for your answer too! :)

Comment: what about these kind of selections `col[class*="col-"]`, Does this hyphen plays any role here?

Comment: @PrasanthKC they play the same role like in `.col[class*="Something"]` for selecting `any containing` like i.e. targets: `col nameSomethingProperty` So basically it's all about readability and ease of use like I said in my comment.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan so i think that is also a main reason to use these hyphens, because if we select a class name with `col` using attrib selector, it may select all the class names containing `col` in it, like `.column` & `.col-span`

Comment: @PrasanthKC exactly. Acting like a *safe delimiter*.

Answer (score 3):

In  addition to being more readable, they can also suggest which classes are related to other. Twitter Bootstrap buttons, for example, have classes like

```
btn
btn-danger
btn-sm
```

etc.

The second two are related in usage to the first

Answer (score 0):

It is just a for **readability**. you may use any names as per convention.