# How to put background image directly to a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a div like this:

[image]

Now I need to remove a part of the circle from this shape which is shown as below:

[image]

Therefore the final shape would be looked like this:

[image]

So I decided to put the image as the background of my div.

```
<div class="col-4 customBack">  
    <div class="mainInfo">
        <div class="circle2">
            <img src="https://sitename.com/images/image.png">   
        </div>
        <div class="paraDivRight2">
            <h6 style="margin-top:5px;"><strong>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Simit</strong></h6>
            <hr style="margin-top:-5px;">
            <p style="margin-top:-10px;">012-3456789</p>
            <p style="padding-top:5px;">ifno@sitename.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here are the styles:

```
.mainInfo{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: .01rem round #e0e1ed;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #585CA1;
    width:100%;
    height:5em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    margin-top: 3em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.customBack{
    background-image: url("/img/shadow3.png") !important;
}

.circle2 {
    position: relative;
    left:-60%;
    width: 9em;
    height: 9em;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}

.circle2 img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 85%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 100;
}

.paraDivRight2 {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    color:black;
    top:0px !important;
    padding-top:50px !important;
    right: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right:50px !important;
}

.paraDivRight2 p {
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

As you can see I have put the background in `.customBack` class But the result is now looks like this:

[image]

So the question is, how can I properly place this background image which is (`shadow3.png`) as background image of this `mainInfo` div so the side of circle shape that needs to be removed, does not appear...

I'm really stuck with this, so please help me out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use CSS [`filter: drop-shadow()` MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) on a wrapper element.
- Fix your class naming to use a [friendlier convention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20811509/383904)
- Use CSS flex for a simpler alignment of your elements
- Stop using inline HTML `style` attributes

```css
/* Quick Reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.custom {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.custom-image {
  width: 9em;
  height: 9em;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.custom-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.custom-content {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 0 1em 1em 0;
  padding-left: 2em;
  left: -1em;
}

.custom-content h4 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom">
  <div class="custom-image">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCWYU.jpg?s=256&g=1">
  </div>
  <div class="custom-content">
    <h4>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Simit</h4>
    <p>012-3456789</p>
    <p>ifno@sitename.com</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Roko, I've got question about this, I can not properly make the `custom-content` class wider! I mean it collapses the `content-image`

Comment: Dear @nagidi if I got your question right, add to `.custom` this: `flex-wrap: nowrap;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Answer (score -2):

I'm not 100% sure about this but it has worked for me in the past,try making the  `position` attribute of the div relative  and make it absolute for the image,then size it properly.