# How to move child elements in carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm making a simple JS slider and I want to change the order of the images when I click on the prev/next button:

```html
<div id="slider-container">
  <div class="btn" id="prevBtn">
    <i class="arrow arrowLeft"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="multiple-items">
    <div>
      <img class="carousel-img" src="assets/carousel/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="carousel-img" src="assets/carousel/img2.png">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="carousel-img" src="assets/carousel/img3.png">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="carousel-img" src="assets/carousel/img4.png">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="carousel-img" src="assets/carousel/img5.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn" id="nextBtn">
    <i class="arrow arrowRight"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to switch `img2` with `img1` and `img1` goes to the `img5` place.

[image: example]

JS code, added listeners to buttons:

```
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
if (i > 1) {
    i--
} else {
    i = 5;
}
});

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (i < 5) {
        i++
    } else {
        i = 1;
    }
})
```

Comment: By *"switch"* you mean to **animate** your carousel? If yes, why did you not mentioned it? Please read [ask]. [edit] with a [mcve] of your best try. There's lack of obvious things like mentioning if the carousel should stop at the last slide or be infinite (I suppose), how to handle the buttons etc

Comment: I just forgot to add js code, I have a long time not coded, so I forgot a lot things, I think it can be done with js methods, but cant realize how to do that.

Comment: Semantics any accessibility matter, don't use `<div>` when you actually need `<button type="button" aria-title="next slide">`, Also don't limit yourself of having the possibility to have only one such component per page. Use classes instead of IDs

Comment: My english level is not too high, so bcs of that my question is not that easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

To do what you require you can select the `:first-child`/`:last-child` `div` elements and `append()`/`prepend()` them within their respective container:

```js
const carousel = document.querySelector('.multiple-items');

document.querySelector('#prevBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const last = carousel.querySelector('div:last-child');
  carousel.prepend(last);
});

document.querySelector('#nextBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const first = carousel.querySelector('div:first-child');
  carousel.append(first);
});
```

```css
.multiple-items > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider-container">
  <div class="btn" id="prevBtn">
    <i class="arrow arrowLeft">Prev</i>
  </div>
  <div class="multiple-items">
    <div>
      <img class="carousel-img" src="assets/carousel/img1.png" alt="img1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="carousel-img" src="assets/carousel/img2.png" alt="img2" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="carousel-img" src="assets/carousel/img3.png" alt="img3" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="carousel-img" src="assets/carousel/img4.png" alt="img4" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="carousel-img" src="assets/carousel/img5.png" alt="img5" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn" id="nextBtn">
    <i class="arrow arrowRight">Next</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could be me, but looks like you reversed _next_ and _Prev_, lol

Comment: @icecub you're right, I did! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use IDs. You're limiting yourself to not being able to reuse your component inside a page. Use classes instead and have as many carousels as you desire
- Use `<button>` instead of `<div>`
- Use a live HTMLCollection by using [Element.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children)
- Use [.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) and [.prepend()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend) Element methods
- Use a more consistent [CSS naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20811902/383904)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.slider').forEach((elSlider) => {

  const elItems = elSlider.querySelector(".slider-items");
  const slides = elItems.children;

  elSlider.querySelector(".slider-btn.prev").addEventListener("click", () => {
    elItems.prepend(slides[slides.length - 1]);
  });

  elSlider.querySelector(".slider-btn.next").addEventListener("click", () => {
    elItems.append(slides[0]);
  });

});
```

```css
.slider-items {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-items">
    <div><img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100/0bf?text=1" alt="img1"></div>
    <div><img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100/fb0?text=2" alt="img2"></div>
    <div><img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100/f0b?text=3" alt="img3"></div>
    <div><img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100/bf0?text=4" alt="img4"></div>
    <div><img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100/b0f?text=5" alt="img5"></div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="slider-btn prev" aria-label="previous">&larr;</button>
  <button type="button" class="slider-btn next" aria-label="next">&rarr;</button>
</div>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-items">
    <div><img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100/222?text=1" alt="img1"></div>
    <div><img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100/444?text=2" alt="img2"></div>
    <div><img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100/666?text=3" alt="img3"></div>
    <div><img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100/888?text=4" alt="img4"></div>
    <div><img src="//via.placeholder.com/100x100/ccc?text=5" alt="img5"></div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="slider-btn prev" aria-label="previous">&larr;</button>
  <button type="button" class="slider-btn next" aria-label="next">&rarr;</button>
</div>
```

Thanks to the live HTMLCollection, with the example above you can also add or remove slides **dynamically**; the script will still work as expected.

---

What is still missing in the above is a better UI/UX. In the real world things do not *teleport*; users are used to cognitively perceive motion through animation. But that's another question.