# close a div+id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can have a div called:

closemenu + number like this:

```
closemenu21
closemenu7778
closemenu9392392392
```

my problem is, I want to hide all divs with closemenu that are open, so I tried:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (){
    var container = $(".closemenu");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

the problem is .closemenu is not the name of my divs, since it can be .closemenu plus any number.

How can I hide() all .closemenu plus numbers in this function?

Comment: `closemenuNUMBER` what is this? A class or an id?

Comment: the number is an id @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: add a class `closemenu` to your div's. `closemenu[number]` should be an id

Comment: This question/answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055355/jquery-select-an-element-that-the-class-starts-with